# Silverlight Open File

Tags: silverlight, file, openfiledialog

If i've got a filepath that the current browsers computer can access. Is there anyway that a silverlight application can open that file?

I dont want to run out of browser if possible as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, not possible without running out of browser, and even then I think only certain filepaths are available.

Answer (score 6):

In Silverlight 4 [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is the only option to access any place on the file system. Elevated trust, out of browser applications can access the current user folder only. However, in Silverlight 5 this type of application will be able to access anywhere on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

From new features of Silverlight 5 at:
http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/future/

> Silverlight 5 extends features of the
>   ‘Trusted Application’ model to the
>   browser for the first time. These
>   features, when enabled via a group
>   policy registry key and an application
>   certificate, mean users won’t need to
>   leave the browser to perform complex
>   tasks:
>
> Host HTML content as a Web browser
>   control within the Silverlight
>   application. HTML pages, such as help
>   content or e-mail, can be integrated
>   within the application. Read and write
>   files to the user’s My Documents
>   folder, making it easier to find media
>   files or create local copies of
>   reports. Launch Microsoft Office and
>   other desktop programs. Users can open
>   Microsoft Outlook and create an e-mail
>   message, or send a report to Word
>   utilizing the power of Office. Access
>   devices and other system capabilities
>   by calling into application COM
>   components. Users can access a USB
>   security card reader or a bar-code
>   scanner. Enjoy full keyboard support
>   in full screen, which enables richer
>   kiosk and media viewing applications.
>   Call existing unmanaged code directly
>   from within Silverlight with PInvoke.

Note that this feature is available only on the Windows platform.